# Why does a hyperplane have a dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra

The hyperplane $H$ defined by $$H:=\{x\in\mathbb {R}^n:a^Tx=b\}.$$The text claims it to have a dimension $n-1$ but for it to have a dimension doesn't $H$ have to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$? But clearly for $b\not =0$, this would not be a subspace and therefore why can we say it has a dimension? Many thanks!

Comment: You are right it is not a vector space, so the book probably didn't define what the dimension of $H$ is. But as an [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) or as a [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold),  $H$ has dimension $n-1$ :)